# Check if a function exists inside another function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, webpack

Propose the following situation:

```
function functionExists(functionName) {
    if (typeof window[functionName] == 'function') console.log("It's a function");
}
```

What would be an equivalent function in `nodejs` for `functionExists` where there is no global `window` variable?

**CONCRETE SITUATION:**

My concrete situation uses `webpack` instead of `nodejs`, but basically the problem is the same. I could use `window` here, but it would be too complicated to implement everything cleanly, and it isn't advised by `webpack` to mitigate things out to the `window` global variable.

Basically, I have a `PHP` backend, which generates a html `<form>` adding some options to it via a `data` attribute. When the page is loaded, my javascript initializes this `<form>` and gives it a bunch of functionalities (like validation for example). Another thing javascript does with this form, is that it parses the data attribute of it, and instead of the normal page reload submit, it changes the form so it is being submited over an `ajax` request to the server.

When this submit happens, it is set up, that the button and the whole form gets disabled, until my `Ajax` script sends back a response. How this is done, is that I have a `Project_Form` class, which when it is initialized, attaches itself to the `jQuery` submit event, stops the basic submit event, and runs an inner function which sends an ajax request to an api method. The ajax request is set up, that when a response is received, the same instantiated class will receive this response, so I can continue working with it.

When the form receives the response, it must do something with it. In the most basic situation, it must show a success message to the user, but there are some more complex situation, where for example, it has to make a page redirect (for example a login form). Right now, it is set up, that as a default, it will show a message, but when I define this form in PHP, I have the option to "hijack" this default behaviour, and instead of it, send the ajax response to a custom function, which will resolve the situation specifically.

When I am rendering the form in PHP, I already know where the form should send a success response (to which javascript function), but I can only provide this information to javascript, via a string. So my `Project_Form` class, should fetch this string, and should try to fetch a function from it which it will use. This is where my problem is coming from.

Comment: Nodejs doesn't have a global namespace but just some variables like - `__dirname, __filename, exports, module`. What is the use case u are trying to solve? Quote from the Doc - `In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node.js module will be local to that module.`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you specifically KNOW that this is a global function (which is almost never the case in nodejs), functions by default in nodejs are scoped to the module and there is NO way to look them up by string name like you did with the `window` object in the browser, just like there is no way to look up local variables by name inside a function in Javascript.

In general, don't pass functions by string name. Or, if you have to, then you need to create a lookup table that you can check the function name against.

**I'd suggest you explain the real problem you're trying to solve here because passing the function by string name is not how you would generally want to do things.**

There is a bit of a hack using `eval()` that can see if a string represents a function name that is in scope:

```
// Warning, you must know that the argument f (if it is a string) does not
// contain harmful Javascript code because it will be used with eval()
function isFunction(f) {
   // if already a function reference
   if (typeof f === "function") {
       return true;
   // see if string represents a function name somewhere in scope
   } else if (typeof f === "string") {
       try {
           return eval(`typeof ${f} === "function"`);
       } catch(e) {
           return false;
       }
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Note: This tests to see if the function is in the scope of the `isFunction()` function.  If you want to test if it's in your current scope, then you need to do the:

```
eval(`typeof ${f} === "function"`)
```

inline in your current scope so it runs in the scope you want to do the lookup from.

To ever consider using this, you will HAVE to know that the source of your string is safe and cannot contain harmful code.  But, as I said earlier, it's better to design your program differently so you aren't referring to functions by their string name.

And, here's a runnable snippet that shows it in action (also works in a node.js module):

```js
function test() {
    console.log("in test");
}

function isFunction(f) {
   // if already a function reference
   if (typeof f === "function") {
       return true;
   // see if string represents a function name somewhere in scope
   } else if (typeof f === "string") {
       try {
           return eval(`typeof ${f} === "function"`);
       } catch(e) {
           return false;
       }
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

console.log(isFunction("test"));          // true
console.log(isFunction(test));            // true
console.log(isFunction("notAFunction"));  // false
```

---

**More added after question edit**

If you only have the function name as a string and the function that it points to is not a property of some known object, then the only way I know of to turn that string into a function reference is with `eval()`.

You could directly execute it with `eval()` such as `eval(functionName + "()")` or you could get a reference to the function with `eval("let fn = " + functionName)` and then use the newly defined `fn` variable to call the function.

If you control the various functions that could be referenced (because they're your Javascript), then you can make all those functions be a property of a known object in your Javsacript:

```
 const functionDispatcher = {
      function1,
      function2,
      function3,
      function4
 }
```

Then, instead of using `eval()`, you can reference them off the `functionDispatcher` object like you would have referenced before with `window` (except this isn't a global) as in:

```
functionDispatcher[someFunctionName]();
```

This would be a preferred option over using `eval()` since there is less risk of insertion of random code via an unsafe string.

Comment: I provided a concrete situation, and some details for why I need something like this. If you have any advice, on how should I proceed, i would be very grateful. I can change both `PHP` and `javascript` codes, but I am not able to migrate the whole project to a `javascript` backend unfortunately.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai - I added more to my answer about your latest scenario.  We could have been a lot more specific awhile ago if you would just show us the actual form code and attributes that you're dealing with.  Code examples show 500% more context than just text descriptions and allow us to help solve your exact situation precisely rather than just describing general concepts that you have to grasp and convert to your specific situation.

Comment: @jrfriend00 I know this, but unfortunately this is not just a specific situation but an all around situation in my code. I managed to solve it in the end, with your second advice, by making a fake "global" variable, in where I store references to these functions, so my old function finder can find it if it looks in there, instead of `window` object. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In `node.js` you can achieve this like:

```
function functionExists(functionName) {
 if(functionName && typeof functionName === "function")
 console.log("It is a function");
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I just tried this in node.js by calling `functionExists("test")` where `test` is a function that exists locally.  It did not work.

Comment: All this seems to work with is an actual function reference whereas it appears the OP has a function name as a string, not as a function reference.  If you want to test just a function reference, you can just do `typeof functionReference === "function"`.  I don't understand the point of the `{}.toString.call(functionName)`?